# Cannot Disable Autoplay with Spotify iOS App Remote SDK

Tags: ios, swift, sdk, spotify

I am attempting to disable background Spotify autoplay (through the App Remote SDK) using the following Swift function.

```
private static func configureAppRemote() {
    if let player_api = SpotifySDK.shared.app_remote.playerAPI {
        player_api.setRepeatMode(.off, callback: SpotifySDK.debug_callback)
        player_api.setShuffle(false, callback: SpotifySDK.debug_callback)
        is_configured = true
    } else {
        is_configured = false
    }
}
```

My SpotifySDK.debug_callback prints out the closure parameters of these two calls and returns (result, error) = (nil, nil) for both, even though the Objective-C Spotify SDK source code claims that this state is impossible:

```
@param callback On success `result` will be `YES`.
                On error `result` will be `nil` and `error` will be set.
```

Has anyone figured out how to correctly disable autoplay using App Remote?

Answer (score 1):

What does your session manager look like? I was having the same problem and by commenting out the following from my session manager declaration auto play stopped:

```
lazy var sessionManager: SPTSessionManager = {
    if let tokenSwapUrl = URL(string: "https://conservative-media.herokuapp.com/api/token"),
        let tokenRefreshUrl = URL(string: "https://conservative-media.herokuapp.com/api/refresh_token") {
        self.configuration.tokenSwapURL = tokenSwapUrl
        self.configuration.tokenRefreshURL = tokenRefreshUrl
//            self.configuration.playURI = ""
    }
    let manager = SPTSessionManager(configuration: self.configuration, delegate: self)
    return manager
}()
```

A blank string for playURL will autoplay the user's last played audio and you can also input a valid Spotify URI to play that auto.